# Why C# Object passed to COM method's VARIANT* parameter converted to VT_DISPATCH type

Tags: com, marshalling, variant

I have an ATL COM service which exposes a method that takes in an [in, out] VARIANT pointer as a parameter.

For example, I have the following method for a COM interface, say IMyApiCom:

```
HRESULT Action([in, out] VARIANT* EmptyObj);
```

I wrote a C# client application that calls this, like so:

```
MyApiCom myapi = new MyApiCom();
Object emptyObj = new Object();
myapi.Action(ref emptyObj);
```

Now, when I debug the COM service and check how `EmptyObj` is initialized, it is of type VT_DISPATCH, whereas I expected it to be VT_EMPTY. This causes an issue for me, although it can easily be worked around (by setting it as VT_EMPTY).

Reasons for why I'd prefer it to be VT_EMPTY aside, I'd just like to know why it's initialized as VT_DISPATCH and not VT_EMPTY.

Also, is it possible to pass an object of type VT_EMPTY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get VT_EMPTY in your ATL side, simply pass null (Nothing in VB, nullptr in C++/CLI) in managed code.

Reference:

- [Default Marshaling for Objects: Marshaling Object to Variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x07fbw8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforobjectsanchor3)

Comment: I had assumed all this time that null was not a valid parameter for a [in, out] parameter. My ignorance proved me wrong yet again. Thank you!

Comment: What happened in your original code is that `emptyObj` was an instance of a .NET object - which, it so happens, was of type System.Object - but .NET interop doesn't care. A CCW is created for it, and an IDispatch to the CCW is placed in the parameter.